# LSI MegaRaid 9261-8i detects drives as "Unconfigured Good (Unsupported)"

Tags: megaraid

i just purchased 9 SAS drives to create my home storage. 8 drives will work in Raid 6 and the 9th drive is a spare. however, after purchasing the LSI MegaRaid 9261-8i and connected only 6 drives for testing, the card detects the cards as "Unconfigured Good (Unsupported)". after digging on the internet, i found a similar problem that the drive was formatted with sector size 520, and the solution is to format it with sector size 512B. however, i can't see the drives independently (directly) on Windows10 nor CentOs7.

[MSM detects drives](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jw45l.png)

i have installed MegaRaid Storage Manager on windows and it shows the sector size is 512B. however, when issuing the command `MegaCli64.exe -PDList -aALL`,
it shows that the sector size is 0.
[My LSI Card](https://www.ebay.com/itm/LSI-MegaRAID-SAS-9261-8i-8-Port-6Gb-s-512MB-SATA-SAS-PCI-E-2-0-RAID-Controller/372681473210?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649)
[My HDD Link](https://www.ebay.com/itm/98Y4619-IBM-4TB-3-5-inch-7200-SAS-SED-HDD-With-Tray-ST4000NM0043/392289316671?ssPageName=STRK%3AMEBIDX%3AIT&_trksid=p2057872.m2749.l2649)

```
F:\Downloads\Compressed\8-07-14_MegaCLI\Windows>MegaCli64.exe -PDList -aALL

Adapter #0

Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 0
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 52
WWN: 5000C500563289E4
Sequence Number: 1
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 3.462 TB [0x1bb5bea00 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 3.462 TB [0x1bb4bea00 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 3.461 TB [0x1bb317000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  0
Logical Sector Size:  0
Physical Sector Size:  0
Firmware state: Unconfigured(good), Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: E06A
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5000c500563289e5
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 3(path0)
Inquiry Data: IBM-SSG S7CR4P0         E06AZ1Z0D1K5  02E06A
FDE Capable: Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Supported
Drive Temperature : N/A
PI Eligibility:  No
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 1
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 51
WWN: 5000C50055AAC5C0
Sequence Number: 1
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 3.462 TB [0x1bb5bea00 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 3.462 TB [0x1bb4bea00 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 3.461 TB [0x1bb317000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  0
Logical Sector Size:  0
Physical Sector Size:  0
Firmware state: Unconfigured(good), Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: E06A
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5000c50055aac5c1
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 2(path0)
Inquiry Data: IBM-SSG S7CR4P0         E06AZ1Z055N9  02E06A
FDE Capable: Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Supported
Drive Temperature : N/A
PI Eligibility:  No
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 2
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 50
WWN: 5000C50056328B8C
Sequence Number: 1
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 3.462 TB [0x1bb5bea00 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 3.462 TB [0x1bb4bea00 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 3.461 TB [0x1bb317000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  0
Logical Sector Size:  0
Physical Sector Size:  0
Firmware state: Unconfigured(good), Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: E06A
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5000c50056328b8d
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 1(path0)
Inquiry Data: IBM-SSG S7CR4P0         E06AZ1Z0D1JN  02E06A
FDE Capable: Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Supported
Drive Temperature : N/A
PI Eligibility:  No
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 3
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 53
WWN: 5000C500562714A0
Sequence Number: 1
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 3.462 TB [0x1bb5bea00 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 3.462 TB [0x1bb4bea00 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 3.461 TB [0x1bb317000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  0
Logical Sector Size:  0
Physical Sector Size:  0
Firmware state: Unconfigured(good), Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: E06A
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5000c500562714a1
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 0(path0)
Inquiry Data: IBM-SSG S7CR4P0         E06AZ1Z0CDBW  02E06A
FDE Capable: Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Supported
Drive Temperature : N/A
PI Eligibility:  No
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 4
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 55
WWN: 5000C50056328EB8
Sequence Number: 1
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 3.462 TB [0x1bb5bea00 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 3.462 TB [0x1bb4bea00 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 3.461 TB [0x1bb317000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  0
Logical Sector Size:  0
Physical Sector Size:  0
Firmware state: Unconfigured(good), Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: E06D
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5000c50056328eb9
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 5(path0)
Inquiry Data: IBM-SSG S7CR4P0         E06DZ1Z0DALL  07E06D
FDE Capable: Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Supported
Drive Temperature : N/A
PI Eligibility:  No
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No



Enclosure Device ID: 252
Slot Number: 5
Enclosure position: N/A
Device Id: 54
WWN: 5000C50055B43CE0
Sequence Number: 1
Media Error Count: 0
Other Error Count: 0
Predictive Failure Count: 0
Last Predictive Failure Event Seq Number: 0
PD Type: SAS

Raw Size: 3.462 TB [0x1bb5bea00 Sectors]
Non Coerced Size: 3.462 TB [0x1bb4bea00 Sectors]
Coerced Size: 3.461 TB [0x1bb317000 Sectors]
Sector Size:  0
Logical Sector Size:  0
Physical Sector Size:  0
Firmware state: Unconfigured(good), Spun Up
Device Firmware Level: E06A
Shield Counter: 0
Successful diagnostics completion on :  N/A
SAS Address(0): 0x5000c50055b43ce1
SAS Address(1): 0x0
Connected Port Number: 4(path0)
Inquiry Data: IBM-SSG S7CR4P0         E06AZ1Z05N22  02E06A
FDE Capable: Capable
FDE Enable: Disable
Secured: Unsecured
Locked: Unlocked
Needs EKM Attention: No
Foreign State: None
Device Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Link Speed: 6.0Gb/s
Media Type: Hard Disk Device
Drive:  Not Supported
Drive Temperature : N/A
PI Eligibility:  No
Drive is formatted for PI information:  No
PI: No PI
Port-0 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s
Port-1 :
Port status: Active
Port's Linkspeed: 6.0Gb/s
Drive has flagged a S.M.A.R.T alert : No




Exit Code: 0x00
```

---

```
F:\Downloads\Compressed\8-07-14_MegaCLI\Windows>MegaCli64.exe -AdpAllInfo -aALL

Adapter #0

==============================================================================
                    Versions
                ================
Product Name    : LSI MegaRAID SAS 9261-8i
Serial No       : SV20503315
FW Package Build: 12.15.0-0239

                    Mfg. Data
                ================
Mfg. Date       : 01/30/12
Rework Date     : 00/00/00
Revision No     : 15A
Battery FRU     : N/A

                Image Versions in Flash:
                ================
FW Version         : 2.130.403-4660
BIOS Version       : 3.30.02.2_4.16.08.00_0x06060A05
Preboot CLI Version: 04.04-020:#%00009
WebBIOS Version    : 6.0-54-e_50-Rel
NVDATA Version     : 2.09.03-0058
Boot Block Version : 2.02.00.00-0000
BOOT Version       : 09.250.01.219

                Pending Images in Flash
                ================
None

                PCI Info
                ================
Controller Id   : 0000
Vendor Id       : 1000
Device Id       : 0079
SubVendorId     : 1000
SubDeviceId     : 9263

Host Interface  : PCIE

ChipRevision    : B4

Link Speed           : 0
Number of Frontend Port: 0
Device Interface  : PCIE

Number of Backend Port: 8
Port  :  Address
0        5000c500562714a1
1        5000c50056328b8d
2        5000c50055aac5c1
3        5000c500563289e5
4        5000c50055b43ce1
5        5000c50056328eb9
6        0000000000000000
7        0000000000000000

                HW Configuration
                ================
SAS Address      : 500605b0043623b0
BBU              : Absent
Alarm            : Present
NVRAM            : Present
Serial Debugger  : Present
Memory           : Present
Flash            : Present
Memory Size      : 512MB
TPM              : Absent
On board Expander: Absent
Upgrade Key      : Absent
Temperature sensor for ROC    : Absent
Temperature sensor for controller    : Absent


                Settings
                ================
Current Time                     : 8:3:18 6/17, 2019
Predictive Fail Poll Interval    : 300sec
Interrupt Throttle Active Count  : 16
Interrupt Throttle Completion    : 50us
Rebuild Rate                     : 30%
PR Rate                          : 30%
BGI Rate                         : 30%
Check Consistency Rate           : 30%
Reconstruction Rate              : 30%
Cache Flush Interval             : 4s
Max Drives to Spinup at One Time : 2
Delay Among Spinup Groups        : 12s
Physical Drive Coercion Mode     : 1GB
Cluster Mode                     : Disabled
Alarm                            : Enabled
Auto Rebuild                     : Enabled
Battery Warning                  : Disabled
Ecc Bucket Size                  : 15
Ecc Bucket Leak Rate             : 1440 Minutes
Restore HotSpare on Insertion    : Enabled
Expose Enclosure Devices         : Enabled
Maintain PD Fail History         : Enabled
Host Request Reordering          : Enabled
Auto Detect BackPlane Enabled    : SGPIO/i2c SEP
Load Balance Mode                : Auto
Use FDE Only                     : Yes
Security Key Assigned            : No
Security Key Failed              : No
Security Key Not Backedup        : No
Default LD PowerSave Policy      : Automatic
Maximum number of direct attached drives to spin up in 1 min : 10
Auto Enhanced Import             : Yes
Any Offline VD Cache Preserved   : No
Allow Boot with Preserved Cache  : No
Disable Online Controller Reset  : No
PFK in NVRAM                     : No
Use disk activity for locate     : Yes
POST delay                       : 90 seconds
BIOS Error Handling              : Stop On Errors
Current Boot Mode                 :Normal
                Capabilities
                ================
RAID Level Supported             : RAID0, RAID1, RAID5, RAID6, RAID00, RAID10, RAID50, RAID60, PRL 11, PRL 11 with spanning, SRL 3 supported, PRL11-RLQ0 DDF layout with no span, PRL11-RLQ0 DDF layout with span
Supported Drives                 : SAS, SATA

Allowed Mixing:

Mix in Enclosure Allowed
Mix of SAS/SATA of HDD type in VD Allowed
Mix of SAS/SATA of SSD type in VD Allowed

                Status
                ================
ECC Bucket Count                 : 0

                Limitations
                ================
Max Arms Per VD          : 32
Max Spans Per VD         : 8
Max Arrays               : 128
Max Number of VDs        : 64
Max Parallel Commands    : 1008
Max SGE Count            : 80
Max Data Transfer Size   : 8192 sectors
Max Strips PerIO         : 42
Max LD per array         : 16
Min Strip Size           : 8 KB
Max Strip Size           : 1.0 MB
Max Configurable CacheCade Size: 0 GB
Current Size of CacheCade      : 0 GB
Current Size of FW Cache       : 0 MB

                Device Present
                ================
Virtual Drives    : 0
  Degraded        : 0
  Offline         : 0
Physical Devices  : 7
  Disks           : 6
  Critical Disks  : 0
  Failed Disks    : 0

                Supported Adapter Operations
                ================
Rebuild Rate                    : Yes
CC Rate                         : Yes
BGI Rate                        : Yes
Reconstruct Rate                : Yes
Patrol Read Rate                : Yes
Alarm Control                   : Yes
Cluster Support                 : No
BBU                             : Yes
Spanning                        : Yes
Dedicated Hot Spare             : Yes
Revertible Hot Spares           : Yes
Foreign Config Import           : Yes
Self Diagnostic                 : Yes
Allow Mixed Redundancy on Array : No
Global Hot Spares               : Yes
Deny SCSI Passthrough           : No
Deny SMP Passthrough            : No
Deny STP Passthrough            : No
Support Security                : No
Snapshot Enabled                : No
Support the OCE without adding drives : Yes
Support PFK                     : Yes
Support PI                      : No
Support Boot Time PFK Change    : No
Disable Online PFK Change       : No
PFK TrailTime Remaining         : 0 days 0 hours
Support Shield State            : No
Block SSD Write Disk Cache Change: No
Support Online FW Update        : Yes

                Supported VD Operations
                ================
Read Policy          : Yes
Write Policy         : Yes
IO Policy            : Yes
Access Policy        : Yes
Disk Cache Policy    : Yes
Reconstruction       : Yes
Deny Locate          : No
Deny CC              : No
Allow Ctrl Encryption: No
Enable LDBBM         : No
Support Breakmirror  : No
Power Savings        : No

                Supported PD Operations
                ================
Force Online                            : Yes
Force Offline                           : Yes
Force Rebuild                           : Yes
Deny Force Failed                       : No
Deny Force Good/Bad                     : No
Deny Missing Replace                    : No
Deny Clear                              : No
Deny Locate                             : No
Support Temperature                     : Yes
NCQ                                     : No
Disable Copyback                        : No
Enable JBOD                             : No
Enable Copyback on SMART                : No
Enable Copyback to SSD on SMART Error   : Yes
Enable SSD Patrol Read                  : No
PR Correct Unconfigured Areas           : Yes
Enable Spin Down of UnConfigured Drives : No
Disable Spin Down of hot spares         : No
Spin Down time                          : 30
T10 Power State                         : No
                Error Counters
                ================
Memory Correctable Errors   : 0
Memory Uncorrectable Errors : 0

                Cluster Information
                ================
Cluster Permitted     : No
Cluster Active        : No

                Default Settings
                ================
Phy Polarity                     : 0
Phy PolaritySplit                : 0
Background Rate                  : 30
Strip Size                       : 64kB
Flush Time                       : 4 seconds
Write Policy                     : WB
Read Policy                      : None
Cache When BBU Bad               : Disabled
Cached IO                        : Yes
SMART Mode                       : Mode 6
Alarm Disable                    : No
Coercion Mode                    : 1GB
ZCR Config                       : Unknown
Dirty LED Shows Drive Activity   : No
BIOS Continue on Error           : 0
Spin Down Mode                   : None
Allowed Device Type              : SAS/SATA Mix
Allow Mix in Enclosure           : Yes
Allow HDD SAS/SATA Mix in VD     : Yes
Allow SSD SAS/SATA Mix in VD     : Yes
Allow HDD/SSD Mix in VD          : No
Allow SATA in Cluster            : No
Max Chained Enclosures           : 16
Disable Ctrl-R                   : Yes
Enable Web BIOS                  : Yes
Direct PD Mapping                : No
BIOS Enumerate VDs               : Yes
Restore Hot Spare on Insertion   : Yes
Expose Enclosure Devices         : Yes
Maintain PD Fail History         : Yes
Disable Puncturing               : No
Zero Based Enclosure Enumeration : Yes
PreBoot CLI Enabled              : Yes
LED Show Drive Activity          : Yes
Cluster Disable                  : Yes
SAS Disable                      : No
Auto Detect BackPlane Enable     : SGPIO/i2c SEP
Use FDE Only                     : Yes
Enable Led Header                : Yes
Delay during POST                : 0
EnableCrashDump                  : No
Disable Online Controller Reset  : No
EnableLDBBM                      : No
Un-Certified Hard Disk Drives    : Allow
Treat Single span R1E as R10     : No
Max LD per array                 : 16
Power Saving option              : Don't Auto spin down Configured Drives
Max power savings option is  not allowed for LDs. Only T10 power conditions are to be used.
Default spin down time in minutes: 30
Enable JBOD                      : No
TTY Log In Flash                 : No
Auto Enhanced Import             : No
BreakMirror RAID Support         : No
Disable Join Mirror              : No
Enable Shield State              : No
Time taken to detect CME         : 60s

Exit Code: 0x00
```

Comment: Have you solved this question? Because I have a similar situation.